# Can we call the following pattern DI?

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns

Excuse me for my ignorance. I am pretty new to Java. I have studied about Spring DI. Whatever xml or annotation based configuration that we provide will be used to inject the dependencies declaratively. But, I think we can't change the dependencies dynamically.

So, I have created the following sample code, which can provide the dependencies by extending the class path(code for extending classpath is not shown). Can we call this DI?

**Marker interface**

```
public interface IRule {

}
```

**Interface that extends IRule**

```
public interface IFooRule extends IRule {

     public boolean validate(String json);

}
```

**Class that implements IFooRule**

```
public class FooRuleImplemetor {

    private FooRuleImplemetor implementor;

    private FooRuleImplemetor() {
    }

    public boolean validateRule(String json) {
        --Business Logic--
    }

    public static synchronized FooRuleImplemetor getInstance() {
        if (implementor == null) {
            implementor = new FooRuleImplemetor();
        }
        return implementor;
    }
}
```

**Rules Factory. One factory class for virtually any class that IS-A IRule**

```
public class RulesFactory {
    public <T extends IRule> T getRuleImplementation(String clazz) {
        try {
            Class<?> ruleObject = Class.forName(clazz);
            Method factoryMethod = ruleObject.getMethod("getInstance");
            return (T) factoryMethod.invoke(null);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            logger.error("ClassNotFoundException", e);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            logger.error("IllegalAccessException", e);
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            logger.error("SecurityException", e);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            logger.error("NoSuchMethodException", e);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            logger.error("IllegalArgumentException", e);
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            logger.error("InvocationTargetException", e);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**XML Configuration (Only part of it)**

```
<rule>
    <action class="com.mycompany.FooRuleImplemetor">
<rule>
```

The xml that is not part of the class path will be read dynamically. The client will be handed over an instance of the FooRuleImplemetor as shown below(with the class read from xml).

```
RulesFactory rulesFactory = new RulesFactory();
IFooRule fooRule = rulesFactory.getRuleImplementation(clazz);
```

What is the name of this kind of pattern? Can we call this Dependency Injection?

**Update**

I would also like to know the potential disadvantages with this pattern, if there are any. Are there alternative patterns that are well tested that I can use?

Comment: This is like DI, but simpler (you aren't really injecting deps, just looking them up on the fly). Having hand-rolled something like this a few months ago and used it for a while, I would *strongly* recommend switching to a light DI solution (perhaps Guice) as soon as possible. Keep to constructor (param) injection and you won't make a mess, but this is not worth rolling yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you describe is more like a **service locator**, which you use to resolve the dependency. But the dependency itself is not injected -- there is no inversion of control, you control the dependency resolution through the `rulesFactory.getRuleImplementation(clazz)` call.

From Martin Fowler's [Inversion of Control Containers and the Dependency Injection pattern](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html#ServiceLocatorVsDependencyInjection) (which I recommend you read):

> The fundamental choice is between Service Locator and Dependency Injection. The first point is that both implementations provide the fundamental decoupling that's missing in the naive example - in both cases application code is independent of the concrete implementation of the service interface. The important difference between the two patterns is about how that implementation is provided to the application class. With service locator the application class asks for it explicitly by a message to the locator. With injection there is no explicit request, the service appears in the application class - hence the inversion of control.

[The disadvantages are arguable](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/) since as with most patterns it depends on your requirements. Therefore, I'd call them trade-offs instead.

In this case, they come as a result of the main advantage (decoupling). When designing for modularity, remember to minimize coupling but also to maximize cohesion. Hence, make sure you are not creating too finely grained modules.

To name some of the trade-offs:

- It makes your code less clear.
- Makes maintenance harder.
- You lose some compile-time checks, which implies potential run-time errors.

My recommendation would be to use it only if you have stable interfaces with several implementations, or if at least you are sure that there will be another one soon. Just don't go for it just in case some day there might be another implementation of your interface. If you do you most likely will find yourself over-engineering at the expense of things like compile-time checks or IDE aids.

This is mostly common ground for both service locator and dependency injection patterns.